# There is something wrong with my friendly URL's pattern

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following pattern:

```
#.htaccess file

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^member/exit member.php?logout=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^picture/(.*)/(.*) picture.php?cid=$1&pid=$2  #<<======== This line is the target
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?usr=$1 [L]
#...

</IfModule>
```

Also, the code that in the template file is as follows:

```
<div>
    <a href="{if="$modewrite == 1"} picture/{$value.cat_id}/{$value.pic_id} {else} picture.php?cid={$value.cat_id}&amp;pid={$value.pic_id} {/if}" onmousemove="showBigPic(this,'showPicThumb',event);" onmouseout="mouseNoFollow();"><img src="../../{$thumbsFolder}/{$value.pic_name}" alt="{$value.pic_title}" title="{$value.pic_title}" /><span class="Imglayer"></span></a>
</div>
```

The result is:

[image]

Compared to my pattern:

```
Url    :  picture/3/index.php   
Pattern: ^picture/(.*)/(.*)
```

**Why does that wrong result occur, what's wrong with my pattern?**

Comment: did your remove the [L]?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I have added `[L]`  before but the problem still occurred.

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews`. It is often the culprit, when you have such partial overlaps between your "fake" paths, and existing file names.

Comment: @CBroe: I have used this `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes` and the problem is solved. is that right?

Comment: Well if the rest worked before, then you probably don't need the other two. Unless they were there before already. (`FollowSymLinks` or `FollowSymLinksIfOwnerMatch` are a requirement for rewriting to work in the first place, and `Indexes` determines whether requesting a folder shows a listing of the files in it, or a 403 Forbidden.)